# assign a value of dictionary's key into a variable

Tags: python

I have the following code in Python:

```
def buildXmlUpdate(dfrom, roomId, ldays):   

    start_date_sard.text = dfrom
    roomId = str(roomId) 
    room_id_sard.text = roomId
    ldays = {'avail': str(), 'price': str()}
    availability_in_data.text = ldays['avail']
    price_in_data.text = ldays['price']

    for n in ldays:
        print (dfrom, roomId, ldays)
```

Now when running

```
buildXmlUpdate ('21/12/2015', 1, [{'avail': 1, 'price': 100}, {'avail': 3, 'price': 120}])
```

I get the following output

```
('21/12/2015', '1', {'avail': '', 'price': ''})
('21/12/2015', '1', {'avail': '', 'price': ''})
```

In other words:

```
('21/12/2015', '1', {'avail': 1, 'price': 100})
('21/12/2015', '1', {'avail': 3, 'price': 120})
```

As you see here, the dictionary `avail` and `price` keys are set to an empty string but I want to set them according to the `ldays` arguments in the method.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're specifically overwriting the value passed as `ldays` with your own hard-coded value. Why are you doing that?

Comment: In addition to what @DanielRoseman said, can you specify more about `price_in_data.text`, `availability_in_data.text` and etc. I guess these are the XML elements but something is missing here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

```
def buildXmlUpdate(dfrom, roomId, ldays):   

start_date_sard.text = dfrom
roomId = str(roomId)  
room_id_sard.text = roomId
#ldays = {'avail': str(), 'price': str()}
#availability_in_data.text = ldays['avail']
#price_in_data.text = ldays['price']


for n in ldays:
    print (dfrom, roomId, n)
    #availability_in_data.text = get.ldays['avail']
    #price_in_data.txt = get.ldays['price']
    ldays[-1]['avail'] = str(ldays[-1]['avail'])
    ldays[-1]['price'] =str(ldays[-1]['price'])
    availability_in_data.text = ldays[-1]['avail']
    price_in_data.text = ldays[-1]['price']
```

Thank you all!